# How to check if a value exists or not in objectB which is inside ObjectA, if ObjectB may or maynot exist

Tags: javascript

Suppose we want the value in variable val.

Scenario 1 :

```
Var ObjectA = {ObjectB:{val:"text"}}
```

if we want to get value in val, we can access like `ObjectA.ObjectB.val`.
And We'll get `"text"`

Scenario 2:

```
Var ObjectB = {}
```

if I want to get value in val (which is not there), And If I try to access like `ObjectA.ObjectB.val`
We'll get

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined
>           at :1:5

The rules are

1. we cannot make any values null or initialise any values, We'll simply get these values and must use them.
2. If `ObjectB` exists inside `ObjectA` it doesn't means that val exists inside the `ObjectB`.

All I want to know is just if there exists a value in variable val or not without disturbing any other things.

Comment: Why can't you just chain access? ObjectA && ObjectA.ObjectB && ObjectA.ObjectB.val or equivalent using any path-based lib etc?

Comment: Don't do "the rules are". That's code golf. Stack Overflow is not for code golfing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/test-for-existence-of-nested-javascript-object-key

Comment: @zixuan this would promptly be closed as off-topic on Code Golf due to non-objective scoring criteria...

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Clearly, you can see "the rules are". I'm not saying this should be migrated to Code Golf, I'm just saying that I would change that part of the question to something different.

Comment: @zixuan It wasn't clear to me that you _weren't_ suggesting a migration in your previous comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test for existence of nested JavaScript object key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/test-for-existence-of-nested-javascript-object-key)

Answer (score 2):

I would do this by checking each thing in sequence:

```
if(ObjectA && ObjectA.ObjectB && ObjectA.ObjectB.val) {
    // Do something with ObjectA.ObjectB.val
}
```

---

If that construction is too clumsy for you, then two other possibilities come to mind:

- Fill in a default value at each stage, i.e. `((ObjectA || {}).ObjectB || {}).val`
- Test only the innermost value, but inside a `try...catch` block (and silently discard the inevitable error if one of the outer values is missing).

However, those are both harder to read and less performant than the &&-chaining version, so I would only consider them if your chain is very long.

Comment: With the [optional chaining proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining) this can be simplified to `ObjectA?.ObjectB?.val`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Does that proposal have any support in web browsers at this point?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of but there is a [babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining) that allows you to use it in projects where the codebase is already being transpiled.

Answer (score 0):

If the key you are looking for is too nested you could use a tool like [get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.14#get) from lodash (you can also add a default value if the key isn't there).

Either way you can check for existence like this:

```js
let myVal = null;
if (ObjectA && ObjectA.ObjectB && ObjectA.ObjectB.val) myVal = val;
```

Some caveats of this solution is that if `val` is valued to `false`, for example if the value is `0` or `false` (You can read more about it [here](https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/)) the value will still be `null`. You can avoid this by using the unary operator `typeof`:

```js
let myVal = null;
if (typeof ObjectA !== "undefined" && typeof ObjectA.ObjectB !== "undefined" && typeof ObjectA.ObjectB.val !== "undefined") myVal = val;
```